# Demo SERP view of structured data

Tags: structured-data

Is there any way to view your structured data live as you would see it in the actual search results?

For example[image] -

I'm sure there was something like this before, where you enter your URL and it was display a demo SERP, but I cannot seem to find it anywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually rich snippets are generated from limited set of types and properties. Those are

- breadcrumb
- ratings (amount of votes, aggregated rating note),
- price,
- currency
- availability
- date
- author
- duration (food preparation)
- location (events)

Some types of rich snippets Google shows independently of existence of structured markup on the site. For example Google is able to recognize breadcrumbs without structured markup and shows them, if it means, it would be good for UX.

Appearing of rich snippets, even if error-free structured markup exists on the page is not guaranteed by Google.

[This](https://www.ranktank.org/serpitude-serp-rich-snippet-testing-tool/) free but pretty sophisticated tool does the rich snippet preview for you.

[Here](http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/rich-snippets-testing-tool-bookmarklet) is a bookmarklet for testing a current page with the Google's structured data testing tool:

```
javascript:void(window.open(%27https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?url=%27+window.location.href,%27_blank%27));
```